# How to get a default set of data for all the views in Django?

Tags: django

Suppose I have a list of item (say categories) which need to be shown in the header bar of my base template.

The base template will have a content block such that different views will feed with different contents. The problem is that I don't want to have all views return the categories list to the page. It will lead to maintenance issue.

Is there a way such that all the views will returns a specific list of object so that I don't need to add it in the context dictionary in the response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/) for this, but the best bet is probably to use [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/) to render the blocks.